# What is the minimum nonzero rank in a random subspace of matrices?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, pr.probability, linear-algebra, matrices

Fix positive integers $m$, $n$, and $k\leq mn$, and draw a $k$-dimensional subspace $S\leq\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ uniformly from the Grassmannian.

> What is known about the random variable
> $R(m,n,k):=\min\{\operatorname{rank}(A):0\neq A\in S\}$?

Some observations:

- $R(m,n,mn)=1$.
- $R(m,n,1)=\min\{m,n\}$ a.s.
- $R(n,n,2)\leq n-1$ whenever $n\geq3$ is odd. This is a fun puzzle for linear algebra students.
- As Will Sawin [points out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412908/what-is-the-minimum-nonzero-rank-in-a-random-subspace-of-matrices#comment1058219_412908), if $r\in\{1,\dotsc,\min\{m,n\}\}$ satisfies $(m-r)(n-r)>k$, then $R>r$ a.s. This is a consequence of the parametric transversality theorem.
- Following Will Sawin's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412908/what-is-the-minimum-nonzero-rank-in-a-random-subspace-of-matrices#comment1058219_412908), one may show that the probability that $R(2,2,2)=1$ equals the probability that the product of two $2\times 2$ matrices with iid $N(0,1)$ entries has real eigenvalues, which was computed to be $\frac{\pi}{4}$ by Lakshminarayan in [On the number of real eigenvalues of products of random matrices and an application to quantum entanglement](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7601).

(Note: I changed $r\mapsto k$ to avoid confusion between subspace dimension and matrix rank.)

Comment: If $(m-k)(n-k)  >r$ then containing a matrix of rank $\leq k$ is a condition of codimension $(m-k)(n-k)-r >0$ and so occurs with probability $0$. So this gives a lower bound. For your final question, isn't $R(2,2,2)$ not almost surely constant? For the subspace generated by $A$ and $B$, if $A B^{-1}$ has a real eigenvalue then $R(2,2,2)=1$ and otherwise $R(2,2,2)=2$.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$, might $R(m,n,r) = \max(1, \lceil (m+n-\sqrt{(m-n)^2+4r})/2 \rceil )$ a.s.?

Comment: @aorq Yes, I think that's easy to prove.